# ResponseEntity Api add custom error message in rest API

Tags: java

i'am currently using Spring Rest Api ,and i'am returning a responses to the caller using ResponseEntity API.

i'am wondering how to render responses with the error message with the following Configuration:

```
@GetMapping
ResponseEntity<Page<Users>>  getUsers(){
try {
            usersValidationService.validate(researchCriteria);
        }catch(ValidationException e){
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();// here i want to return an empty list with the custom error message
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(repoUsers.findAll(criteresRecherche.toSpecifications(service), page));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

> `return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();`

Try below:

```
<Page<Users>> list = ... // create a empty list and add custom message according to your class <Page<Users>> 
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(list);
```